# Why is my conditional statement not executing multiple times in a foreach loop? PHP

Tags: php, html, web

Im trying to print out order information that matches to a list of customers depending on if the customer id on the order matches the customer id of the customer. Both customers and orders are stored in arrays and so far I don't have issues with executing my order table  and printing my information. The problem I am having is that only one order is printing for the customer and some customers have multiple orders which should be printing. Ive used a foreach loop to iterate through the orders matching order id to requested customer id, which is coming from a query string. I cant tell why my if statement is not printing for multiple orders when I know that at least 1 is printing.

Here is the code for my customer table that executes when the query string is returned with an id of a customer. The foreach loop at the bottom is where I'm expecting all matching orders to print but it is only giving me one order when I expect in some cases multiple. If there's any other information needed I can supply it. Thanks

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    if (isset($_GET['customer'])) {

        $requestedCustomer = $customers[$_GET['customer']];

        $orders = readOrders('orders.txt');
```

Comment: What data do you get when you dump `$requestedCustomer['id']` and `$orders` ?

Comment: The foreach at the bottom? You mean the commented out one?

Comment: _Small Point_ This line `echo '</table>';` should be inside the IF not outside

Comment: Does this make sense ?? `if ($requestedCustomer['id'] == $order['id']) {`

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier the matched customer is stored in requestedcustomer as its array from the original customers array, and orders is the order array which is returned from calling readOrderts()

Comment: @ChrisHaas no, i shouldnt have kept that, the one above

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think so?

Comment: I am a little surprised that the Customers Id is the same as the Order Id

Comment: @RiggsFolly why?

Comment: Because if I get lucky I will have 100 customers but they will buy 1000's of things. Orders and Customers are different things and therefore their id's would only even be the same ONCE and By Accident

Comment: @RiggsFolly I said in my post that its the customer id associated to the order, its not the order id itself. so yes I have many orders with unique id's but cust id's associated to the orders. Ive tested my statement both values are correct, still my issue is with the loop only printing one order when multiple customers have multiple orders that should be printing

Comment: Right, so help us to help you! Do as @ClémentBaconnier asked in the FIRST COMMENT and show us the arrays, so please dump `$requestedCustomer['id']` and `$orders`

Comment: @RiggsFolly i edited so you can see

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Did you, by any chance, post this question before, or does it only resemble one that has been posted within the last days?

Comment: Would you like to make those readable, or shal I spend time editing them

Comment: @NicoHaase yes but it is a different issue Im having now. Like I mentioned I know that my comparison statement in the bottom foreach loop works in matching the id's, and I am getting correct output, however some customers have multiple orders associated to their id but my loop and if statement only print 1 order when I expect multiple. Ive tried different arrangement of my code but I cant seem to find a solution as to why its happeneing.

Comment: Please don't simply duplicate the question in the comment section. Rather, share your attempts to resolve the problem. If the output is correct, which parts do you struggle with?

Comment: @RiggsFolly all you really need to see is that the 'id' s in both arrays match for some customers, and that match is what im doing im my if statement to print out the order for that customer

Comment: Alternatively a[ `var_export($var)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) does it in a way we can just copy/paste and make use of easiy in any testing we may feel woudl help in answering a question

Comment: @NicoHaase i only get one line of order when I should be getting multiple for some customers.

Comment: Also, how do you identify multiple orders from a single customer? As your orders do not parse a customer number, that sounds pretty difficult

Comment: @NicoHaase well my thought was loop through all the orders in $orders array, and if the id's match, then print a row of that order information associated to that customer via cust id which is also set as the id for the order. And since there multiple orders with the same id to that customer, then each iteration would print another row but that doesn't seem to be happeneing

Comment: Looking through the sample data provided, I'm not seeing a single order that has a duplicated ID, so no second row would ever be shown. The IDs for customers are `2,3,4,5,6,7,16,17,18,19,22,23` and the IDs for orders are `2,3,4,5,6,10,11,15,16,18,19,21,23,24,25,29,30`

Comment: Are you sure you are bringing in the correct field in `readOrders()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked **why** this happens? A single ID cannot be used multiple time in the same array, so if you parse multiple rows with the same ID and write them into the array **using the same ID**, you are overwriting prior orders. Only the last order with that ID is accessible. By comparing the parsed array of orders and the file containing your orders, that should be visible pretty easy.

That's why you usually use **unique** order IDs, and store the user ID within that order

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in `readOrders`. You appear to be clobbering your array each time with `$orders[$order['id']] = $order;` Instead you want `$orders[$order['id']][] = $order;`

```php
function readOrders($filename)
{
    $arr = file($filename) or die('ERROR: Cannot find file');

    // Create our primary order array
    $orders = [];

    $delimiter = ',';

    // reading in customers from file and storing in array of customers

    foreach ($arr as $line) {

        $splitcontents = explode($delimiter, $line);

        $order = array();

        $order['id'] = $splitcontents[1];
        $order['isbn'] = $splitcontents[2];
        $order['title'] = utf8_encode($splitcontents[3]);
        $order['category'] = utf8_encode($splitcontents[4]);

        // Append the order to the array, 
        $orders[$order['id']][] = $order;
    }
    return $orders;
}
```

Then, in your print loop, you don't loop over `$orders`, you instead take the main orders array which is indexed by the customer ID and grab those specific orders.

```php
// Get the orders for this specific customer, if they exist
$customerOrders = $orders[$requestedCustomer['id']] ?? [];
foreach ($customerOrders as $order) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $order['isbn'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $order['title'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $order['category'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```